# usage of external css in ui binder to greyout the particular div at time of submitting the form

Tags: javascript, html, css, uibinder

I want to grey out the particular portion of div during the button click event.
like if we have passed value in two textboxes and clicked the button for submitting the value to database at that time the screen should grey out with all its widgets in disable mode.

i want it to be done in ui binder with help of css,javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#divId1").click(function(event){

   $("#somePortiondivId2").css("background-color",'#ccc');

});
```

In your case:

```
$("#submitId").click(function(event){

   $("#textBox1").prop('disabled', true);
  $("#textBox2").prop('disabled', true);

});
```

Comment: please help me to disable whole div rather than particular textboxes

Comment: i'm using ui binder in gwt where this will not help me

Comment: Please add the complete code here. So that I can help you. Or Follow this 1.Add this code to UI binder or call this after UI binder in document.ready function..

Comment: For whole div : $("#divId").prop('disabled', true);

Comment: this i have in my ui.xml file

Comment: <div class="holder">
      <table align="center">
      
       <tr align="right">
       
          <td>FIRST NAME</td>
          <td id="firstname" ></td>
         
         
         <tr align="right">
         
          <td>LAST NAME</td> 
          <td id="lastname"></td> 
         </tr>
         
         <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td id="button"></td>
         </tr>
        </tr> 
        </table>

Comment: and in my ui binder java class i have the textboxes added.

Comment: i have used a jsni function to display the values of textboxes. I have called the jsni n button click.

Comment: now, i want to the my div area should grey out when i click on submit button, before the values goin to database.

Comment: hope you are getting me.